# Intercept Link Clicks from Frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, frames

I have a old fashion page that uses a frameset containing a top frame and bottom frame. The frameset is defined in "index.html" and my code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#mainFrame').ready(function() {

            $('#mainFrame a').live('click', function() {
                alert('u click');
                return false;
            }); 

        });

    });

</script>

</head>
<frameset id="main" rows="125,*" cols="*">
<frame src="header.html" name="headerFrame" id="headerFrame" />
<frame src="main.html" name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame"  />
</frameset>
</html>
```

I would like to be able to intercept links that are clicked on the frame "mainFrame". I thought I could just add a ready event for it then live bind click events but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Note: The files are all on the same domain so this is not an XSS issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#mainFrame').ready(function() {
    var f = document.getElementById('mainFrame').contentWindow.document;
    $('a', f).live('click', function() {
      alert('u click');
      return false;
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

You just need to add a context to jQuery statement, to tell it where to look for #mainFrame a

Oh yeah....you definitely need to make sure that the iframe is loaded.  The "live" should take care of that...but I'm working on something now where I had to write a custom ready() plugin for jQuery to make sure my frames were loaded, because I was having trouble with Chrome.

Chrome and IE seem to jump the gun on with the document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"...  which I believe is what the ready() functions in jQuery use.

Anyways, just make sure that your iframes get loaded all the way.